# Merge two partitions on one disk to a separate partition on another disk

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount

Here is what I'm trying to do. I have a /home (sda1) and swap (sda2) partition on one disk that I want to merge into a larger swap partition and utilize all of the swap space. When I used the fdisk utility and created my partition (sdb1) I had it use all of the sector space. I then used the mkswap and I think I might have made a mistake doing that at this point because I can't mount sdb1 to anything now without getting the "mount: unknown filesystem type 'swap'" error. This prevents me from using cp. I'm running Fedora 3.10.5 and am working entirely in a terminal window.

Any advice is appreciated. Or let me know how I can phrase the question better if it is poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Warning**: *I hope that you know what you are doing, because in most cases, reformatting `/dev/sda1` on a running system seems like asking for a big trouble!*

One does not mount swap partitions.

After you formatted partition as swap using `mkswap /dev/sda1`, there are 2 ways to make use of new swap partition:

- Manual: use `swapon` utility, something like `swapon /dev/sda1`. It would enable swap partition, but it would not survive reboot.
- Automatic: add lines like this into your `/etc/fstab`:

  ```
  /dev/sda1 none swap sw 0 0
  ```

Then, at boot, it would automatically execute `swapon -a` and enable all swap partitions listed in `/etc/fstab`.

In both cases, utility `free` will list swaps in use, so you can confirm that it really worked.

Alternatively, you don't really have to format partition as swap (and destroy all existing data). You can simply create big non-sparse file on existing partition and mount it as additional swap source. You can read more about this [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/).